# DrumBurp (Drum Tab editor) not working UbuntuStudio 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I install DrumBurp v0.9 for x86 Ubuntu from whatang.org

DrumBurp which is a Drum Tab editor free, but does not work on my 12.04 UbuntuStudio, however works fine in Windows 7 on other machines.

I tried running it on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS which has Python 2.6 inside VirtualBox and it works fine (sound with timidity):

[DrumBurp 0.9 Working on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83295394/DrumBurp/DrumBurp-Working-Fine-on-Ubuntu-10.04-LTS.gif)

I also tried running it on PepperMint (Ubuntu Based Distro) which also has Python 2.6 but did not work. Then I started on my laptop Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD (no install) and run it but it did not work, said there was no sound card.

I do not understand why not working on UbuntuStudio 12.04, and I have not installed on this Laptop Ubuntu 12.04, but here I leave a picture of the terminal:

[DrumBurp doesn't working on UbuntuStudio 12.04](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83295394/DrumBurp/DrumBurp%20do%20not%20open%20on%20UbuntuStudio%2012.04.2%20of%2032bits.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, In UbuntuStudio 14.04 with Wine 1.6

1. Download the program from: http://whatang.org/download/

   Note: This program is portable, not need to install it.
2. Next I install `timidity` package

   ```
    sudo apt-get install timidity
   ```
3. Now use this command in a terminal:

   ```
    modprobe snd_seq
   ```
4. then this one

   ```
    timidity -iA -Os -B2,8 &
   ```

Then a run  DrumBurp.exe and launch it, and working fine when play with drum partitures.